# What is the precise meaning of "preliminary to"?

Tags: semantics

**Clarification**: The point of this question is this: does Event A being "preliminary to" Event B require that Event B has happened or will have happened?

Consider the following sentence:

> "Slaughter prep" means any activity by either prisoner or executioner preliminary to the execution of that prisoner.

Q1: In this sentence, if "that prisoner" was never executed then can any "slaughter prep" have taken place, strictly according to this definition?

(IMHO, if he was never executed, and "slaughter prep" is only those actions that are preliminary to execution, then it stands to reason that no "slaughter prep" took place.)

(NOTE: "Slaughter prep" is not an actual thing. I just invented that phrase for the sake of this question. So probably... don't google it... I doubt the pictures are nice.)

Also consider the following sentence:

> The execution of a prisoner is made possible by the "slaughter prep."

If this is true, we can all agree there can be no execution if there was no "slaughter prep."

NOTE: If your answer to Q1 was "yes," please explain why one event being "preliminary to" another event ought not to require both events be real. Explain it in the context of why while one event "being made possible by" another event must require both events happened. Also, if your answer to Q1 was "yes," is there an alternative to "preliminary" that *would* require both events to be real?

Comment: If completing certain courses is a preliminary step in the process of qualifying for a degree, it seems to me that the act of completing those courses doesn't lose its status as a preliminary step just because a particular person fulfills that step but doesn't go on to earn the degree. In fact, I think that such a person would be speaking entirely accurately if he or she said, "I completed all of the preliminary course work, but I never earned my degree because I didn't submit the independent thesis I wrote on slaughter prep."

Comment: Most "assault" rifles never see battle and most "sports" cars never set treads on a racetrack, yet the names are valid due to their designs having been optimized for such uses. For the same reason, coursework can validly be called "preliminary" notwithstanding low graduation rates. However, it would still be technically incorrect to say, "My completion of the preliminary coursework was preliminary to my being awarded a degree," if you have not been.

Comment: It would be correct to say, "If I ever graduate, then after commencement, my preliminary coursework will have been preliminary to my being awarded a degree."

Comment: If I had voted to close this question—which I almost did—it would have been on the grounds that it isn't so much a question about English language and/or usage as a question about the logical validity of describing something as "preliminary" when (for one reason or another) there turns out to be no main event. In my view, such an inquiry is much more suitable to SE Philosophy ("For those interested in logical reasoning") than to EL&U, where the focus is on how words and phrases are actually used, not on whether a logic machine would find their usage acceptably rigorous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 'yes' - Event A being "preliminary to" Event B requires that Event B has happened or will have happened.

If the execution does not take place, then there was no "slaughter prep". For example: If "slaughter prep" consists of "The Last Meal," and there is no execution, it is not reasonable to assume that it was actually the 'last meal'.

Using the example of the boxing match, (courtesy of T.E.D) if "the main event" does not occur, the preceding contests are not actually "preliminaries" (though they may still be referred to as such) - they are 'the event'.

Comment: Good point. Even if we said that "The Zorostatimajenous Meal" is the meal preliminary to the execution, still, if the execution does not happen, then it's not "The Zorostatimajenous Meal" because there may yet be a "The Zorostatimajenous Meal." Verrrry good point.

Comment: This ignores pragmatics. When Samuel David Crowe was granted clemency by the parole board in the U.S. state of Georgia  [Reuters reported](http://www.reuters.com/article/2008/05/23/us-usa-execution-idUSN2250765020080523) 'Crowe was not present at the parole board hearing in Atlanta. He had already eaten his last meal and was preparing to enter the execution chamber at the prison in Jackson, Georgia, Mallie McCord of the Georgia Department of Corrections said.' On a similar note, you can have your birthday party two days before your birthday. And you might die the following day.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - *if a tree falls in the forest, and no one is there to hear it, does it make a sound?*  In your first example, "last meal" is used as a colloquial expression.  If it was to be taken literally, the reader would have to assume that poor Sam was so traumatized that he never ate again. < *Two mourners standing over your casket* >  "You know, tomorrow **would have been** his birthday?"  "Good thing we celebrated it early - I hate missing out on cake."

Comment: ' "last meal" is used as a [fixed] expression' That's what I'm saying. As is 'birthday party'. And people often use 'prior to', 'before' etc when referring to future events that may not occur. 'I'm having my hair cut before we go away next month.' 'That hedgehog is eating a lot of berries preparatory to hibernating. Oh, he's just seen a treefull on the other side of the motorway ...' Pragmatics doesn't always bear strict scrutiny.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those situations where an analysis based on the sum of the usual meanings of individual words is not going to explain the usage; a (reasonably transparent) idiom is involved.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/preliminary) defines the phrase **preliminary to** thus:

> in preparation for, before, in advance of, prior to, ahead of,
>   preparatory to

and gives as an example

> the geese gather in the estuaries, preliminary to their flight
>   southwards

So *preliminary to* + NP (or *preliminary to* + 'gerund phrase') is an adverbial of time; 'preliminary to the execution of that prisoner' means 'before that prisoner is/was executed'.

Comment: So what is your answer to the OP's question?

Comment: I'm answering the title question. That's a usage question acceptable on ELU. The rest is at best off-topic. Choose legal interpretation, philosophical interpretation, doing coursework for OP ... as the reason.  However, I'd worry about  the use of the term "Slaughter prep" if it looked likely that a prisoner wasn't at least  going to be executed in the very near future. I'd address Q4 by saying 'It is unhelpful and confusing to even use the term "Slaughter prep" if an expected execution hasn't taken place and now looks less than 99.9% certain to.'

Comment: The problem with answering the title rather than the whole question is that it lacks context. There is no 'precise meaning' to that phrase on its own. We need the additional information that we get from the "Slaughter prep" sentence.  At least this user has given some context. It's a rarity on this site.

Comment: The problem with answering the whole OP is that it is off-topic. I like the question as posed in the title, and I think it's valid to answer it; it could well be of use to more than just OP.

Comment: Back on topic. Your answer is *incorrect* if you apply the context of the sentence that we have been given. If you think the phrase is adverbial, what verb does it apply to *in that sentence*?

Comment: As I said in the comment below, adverbial in function,  prepositional in form. 'activities preliminary/prior to the execution of that prisoner.' = 'activities undertaken _prior to the execution of that prisoner_' / _yesterday_ /  _on Tuesday_. The PP is adverbial; the verb is easily recoverable. Obviously, formally, 'preliminary to' is a compound preposition.

Comment: "Coursework for op"? Seriously? I'm 38 years old and hold a degree. Going on ad hominem attacks in the comments in advance of any input from me... not called for, dude. The rest is not off-topic; it's examples of what the force of meaning of "preliminary to" would be. You're missing the point; the point is whether saying Event A is preliminary to Event B requires that Event B has actually happened or will actually happen.

Comment: I've simplified the question above. Feel free to edit your answer accordingly and I'll be glad to pick it as correct if I feel it is.

Comment: I guess the question really is: does "preliminary to" mean both "in preparation for" *and* "before" or can it just be "in preparation for" *but not necessarily* "before"? That's the real question. It's not a philosophical one, either.

Comment: The question needs further clarification. What is the status of the phrase 'slaughter prep'? It doesn't appear to be mentioned in any dictionary or glossary; if it's slang, niche or do-it-yourself, it needs definition here. Is ' "Slaughter prep" means any activity by either prisoner or executioner preliminary to the execution of that prisoner.' a quote from somewhere (in which case it should be attributed)? Is this definition rigorous (and who decided)? Does it include trivia such as breathing, scratching one's back ...   'Preliminary to' has a range of meanings as per ODO, ranging ...

Comment: from a purely temporal 'before' (when pragmatics in everyday usage allows its use when the envisaged future event is not absolutely guaranteed, but when a stricter definition, perhaps demanded by some legal bodies [and hence the need to know more about the provenance of 'slaughter prep'] does not: off-topic here) to 'as part of the preparations for'.

Comment: Well I *did* add clarification, prior to your posting of the last two comments. I added: **"Slaughter prep" is not an actual thing. I just invented that phrase for the sake of this question. So probably... don't google it... I doubt the pictures are nice.** You're focusing too much on what's between the quotation marks. Imagine the sentence was: **"Zoranastacrafawta" means any activity by either prisoner or executioner preliminary to the execution of that prisoner.**

Answer (score 0):

If we examine the definition of 'preliminary' here,

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1.preceding or done in preparation for something fuller or more important:  "a preliminary draft"
>
> synonyms: preparatory · introductory · initial · opening · prefatory ·
>   prior ·  [more]
>
> NOUN
>
> 1.a preliminary action or event:  "the bombardment was resumed as a preliminary to an infantry attack"
>
> synonyms: prelude · preparation · preliminary/preparatory measure
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries][1]
>
> [1]: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/

We can see that it doesn't have an adverbial role. Therefore we must take it to be a noun or an adjective. A noun wouldn't fit syntactically so it must be an adjective.

What does it qualify? Surely it qualifies 'activity'. So we could rewrite,

*"Slaughter prep" means any preliminary activity by either prisoner or executioner to the execution of that prisoner.*

Taking the first definition would give us,

*"Slaughter prep" means any preparatory activity by either prisoner or executioner to the execution of that prisoner.*

I don't think that the executioner would hang himself as a preparation for executing the prisoner but he may have made other preparations, therefore I conclude the answer to your specific question is neither yes or no. It is in fact,

'Without further information, we don't know'.

Comment: But [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preliminary-to) also states that 'preliminary to' is a phrase synonymous with 'prior to' (though the examples it gives do not support this: they use 'preliminary' as the noun).

Comment: I think we have to choose the definition that makes the most sense in the context. Otherwise we may be left with the idea that everything the parties did since they were born was part of the official preliminaries.

Comment: I'm arguing that 'preliminary to (...)' is adverbial (function, if prepositional in form) here, and can be swapped with 'prior to ...' or 'before ...', both notionally adverbials.  The adverbial usage is more obvious in an undeleted version: ' "Slaughter prep" means any activity by either prisoner or executioner which is undertaken preliminary to / before the execution of that prisoner.'

Comment: Okay - That is fair. I don't think it changes the validity of my argument.

Comment: 'Slaughter prep' appears to be very rare on the internet, and I'm guessing it is far from standard, and quite possibly homespun. If this is the true situation, arguing for 'the definition that makes the most sense in the context' cannot make sense. I've been looking at the usage of the phrase 'preliminary to', which _is_ on-topic and certainly licensed by the title.

Comment: As I've said, the title question is on-topic (and I've answered the question – about how 'preliminary to', rather than 'preliminary' – is used). The broadening to 'Can we say X has happened before Y if we're only fairly confident that Y is going to happen?' is philosophy. Or arbitrarily defined semantics. So I've close-voted on those grounds.

Comment: I've simplified the question above. Feel free to edit your answer accordingly and I'll be glad to pick it as correct if I feel it is. Also, I don't think it's fair to call it 'philosophy'. I am trying to know the meaning of the phrase. Just because it deals with the future doesn't make it philosophy.

Comment: By the way, I specifically invented the term "slaughter prep" just for the sake of argument, and *because* it is a never-before-used term (thought that would be obvious, sorry)

Comment: @Comma Toast As there are examples dating back at least 9 years on the internet, (1) you did not 'invent it' and (2) it is far from clear without explanation whether or not it is from a certain domain (which would influence analysis; legal terms tend to be more rigorously defined than say SF nonce words).

Comment: Within my domain of awareness, I invented it. "Invent" as in "To find out or produce by mental activity." (OED, definition #2...) I.e. I did not get that term from another source. I was not aware of other sources. I did not *invent it first* and never claimed to. Anyway please don't focus on the meaning of the words in between the quotation marks there. The point of the example is to limit the meaning of them to solely the definition given by the sentence itself.

Answer (score 0):

The flippant answer it that its a fancy word for "before".

The detailed answer is that word is generally (but not always) used when the first event is required to produce the second, or when putting it first is just how things are typically done.

For instance, when a big boxing match is preceded by several matches of lesser importance those smaller matches are often referred to as preliminary events. They *must be* held earlier because almost nobody would stay to watch them if they were later.

Comment: Right, I get that. But you can't say that Event A happened before Event B, if Event B never happened. So can you say Event A was preliminary to Event B if event B never happened?

Comment: @CommaToast - Perhaps not "was" (past tense), but "is" makes perfect sense. That's informing you what tends to (or must) happen before event B.